# Google Map API Key Issue Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I've generate the api key on https://console.cloud.google.com. and then i use that key in my code like 
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyKey&callback=initMap" in my script tag.
when i visit the generated url then that stated an error:

> You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps
>   Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to
>   http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account

```
    function initMap(){
        //
    }
    var x = document.getElementById('output');

    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation){
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        }
        else{
            x.innerHTML = "Browser Not Compatible";
        }
    }
    function showPosition(position) {
        x.innerHTML = "latitude = "+position.coords.latitude;
        x.innerHTML += "<br>";
        x.innerHTML += "longititude = "+position.coords.longitude;

        var locAPI = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+position.coords.latitude+","+position.coords.longitude+"&sensor=true";
        x.innerHTML = locAPI;

    }
```

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <button id="location-button"
    onclick="getLocation()">Get User Location</button>
    <div id="output"></div>
</div>
```

can some body please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Your keys invalid, there are several reasons why this might be the case. This can't be answered with just the information given here

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed the key param in `showPosition()`. Can you please try this:

```
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "latitude = "+position.coords.latitude;
    x.innerHTML += "<br>";
    x.innerHTML += "longititude = "+position.coords.longitude;

    var locAPI = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+position.coords.latitude+","+position.coords.longitude+"&sensor=true&key=your_key";
    x.innerHTML = locAPI;

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i have attach key on head in my script tag too

Comment: face this error now "This API project is not authorized to use this API"

Comment: Have you [enabled maps](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/google/maps-backend.googleapis.com?folder=&organizationId=) api for the project?

Comment: Then authorize it! Did you read the documentation at all? There is a developer console with various APIs and you need to activate what you want to use.

Comment: how to authorize it

Comment: @FahadButt just clicking on the Enable button should do.

Comment: No Sure why? This is the response using [my API key](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=13.113420267686339,80.20666808280224&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyCOl9rf15PoTGGW2cjO65nGEalZYxFL6-w). Can you post your key for a few minutes?